# Sorting for the heck of it -- Quicksort

Tags: c++, quicksort

We have to make an optimized quicksort for out own Comparable base class. For the life of me I cannot make it work. The algorithm seems straight forward, however I cannot seen to get my code to work. I have a DateTime class that extends Comparable that I am using to test and the sort seems to work but one out of every 20 or so runs a single value is out of place and when I use insertion sort on chunks of the array that are less than 8 the whole sort gets thrown out of whack.

In my partition method it kind of works when I move the pivot to the end and start my pointers at the start and end - 1. I want to move the pivot to end - 1 because the first and last are already sorted and start the pointers at first + 1 and end -2 but everything falls apart if I try that and I don't understand why.

So I have something that works now. It gets a little spastic when I don't use insertion sort on smaller sub arrays which bothers be but ill figure it out eventually. Thanks to ben j for pointing out about falling out of the array...that was causing the insertion sort issue. :)

My current code is below

```
    Comparable** partition(Comparable** from, Comparable** to)
{
    Comparable** pivot  = from + (to - from) / 2;
    SortFirstMiddleLast(from, pivot, to - 1);
    swap(*pivot, *to);
    pivot = to;
    ++from; to -= 2;
    while (from <= to)
    {
        while (**from <= **pivot && from <= to) ++from;
        while (**to   >= **pivot && from <= to) --to;
        if (from < to)
        {
            swap(*from, *to);
            ++from; --to;
        }
    }
    swap(*from, *pivot);
    return from;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you don't really need the `<Comparable*>` for `swap`... it's automatically inferred. :)

Comment: My approach to anything like this is to get it working for integers first, and then modify it to work for other types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you've shown us and your comment about what goes wrong my only guess is that `from` and `to` do not mean what you think.  Your code has `to - from` as the length of the segment to sort.  If that's exact (and not just approximate for pivot selection) that would mean that `to` was actually pointing at an element just beyond the region to sort.  That's reasonable, but then `swap<Comparable*>(*pivot, *(to))` would be swapping the pivot off the end of the list.

Comment: I'm accounting for the to pointer being off by one by adjusting it in the function call...I probably should have included that in my post...is there a way to fix that in the quicksort function without losing an index on subsequent recursive calls?